# Firebase realtime db rules: cascading effect

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Let's say I have a realtime database with the following content:

```
{
  "a1": {
    "b1": {
      "keyb11": "value11"
    },
    "b2": {
      "keyb21": "value21"
    }
  }
}
```

Then I sent as update to Firebase a full JSON object with only 1 new value (line 4):

```
{
  "a1": {
    "b1": {
      "keyb11": "newvalue"
    },
    "b2": {
      "keyb21": "value21"
    }
  }
}
```

The user only has write rights at the level of `b1`.

Should this update pass the FB Rules because although at the level of a1 we don't have write rights, we're not trying to change anything in the a1 or b2 collections? Or would the FB Rules block this because we're sending this as an update of the full JSON object including collections we don't have write rights for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this situation, the write will fail.  A write will fail in its entirety if any of the rules would reject any of the values being written.  This prevents inconsistent results from the perspective of the client doing the writing. Writing is "all or none", and would be deeply confusing to applications otherwise.

If you need to potentially do two writes that may fail independently for whatever reason, you should execute them separately and check the results as such.